# What are the most effective ways to expose multiple product colorways?

Tags: website-design, e-commerce

On an ecommerce category page, what are some effective ways to expose multiple colorways/colors of a particular product?

Standard practice seems to be a scale. On the one end you have the product shown only once, with a simple textual hint, eg: "More Colors". On the other end you have each color shown as if it was a different product. In between, you often see small "swatches" that upon hover will change the image.

Obviously you have trade-offs with these solutions. Are there some particularly effective methods that limit the trade-offs?

Comment: Those trade-offs will vary depending on the application and audience. Do you have a particular implementation target?

Comment: Targeting leans towards 20-40 yr old audience of creatives and professionals interested in premium (yet not ultra lux) apparel pieces under $1k

Answer (score 1):

As above this is pretty dependant on your audience and brand but if your research indicates that colour is a large part of the purchasing decision something like this could be an effective way of putting that front and centre

http://rflx.bjornborg.com/